# Anexar apenas uma linha a um arquivo CSV com pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

estou fazendo um sistema de login utilizando tabelas csv bem básico, pois não é o intuito do programa.

```py
def criar_conta(self, respostas):
  framelogin = pd.read_csv('C:\TCC\Aplicacao\Arquivos CSV\Login_temp.csv', encoding = '#ISO-8859-1')
login = list(framelogin["login"])
senha = list(framelogin["senha"])
respostas.append(login[0])
respostas.append(senha[0])
frameclientes = pd.read_csv('C:\TCC\Aplicacao\Arquivos CSV\Clientes.csv', encoding = '#ISO-8859-1')
```

meu problema é o seguinte:

> Eu preciso incluir o conteúdo da lista `respostas` na última linha do CSV `Clientes.csv` (eu não quero ter que excluir o arquivo antigo e criar um novo com a linha nova, quero que o arquivo seja aberto e escrito nele) se possível gostaria que fosse utilizando a biblioteca pandas.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, bem vamos por partes. Tive um pouco de dificuldade para entender seu problema :)

Considerando que `respostas` é uma lista e que `framelogin` e `frameclientes` são *dataframes*, onde `framelogin` tem dados que não podem se perder, `respostas` são os novos dados e que eles devem ser guardados em `frameclientes`. Temos:

```
import pandas as pd
...

def criar_conta(self, respostas):
    framelogin = pd.read_csv('C:\TCC\Aplicacao\Arquivos CSV\Login_temp.csv', encoding='#ISO-8859-1')
    # transformando a lista em um df para concatenar
    df_respostas = pd.DataFrame('login': respostas[0], 'senha': respostas[1])
    frameclientes = pd.concat([framelogin, respostas], ignore_index=True)
    frameclientes.to_csv('C:\TCC\Aplicacao\Arquivos CSV\Clientes.csv', encoding='#ISO-8859-1')
```